# Is there a better way to use 2 autocomplete address fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the below code to auto find street names, but

1. It does not seem to work very efficiently and
2. When there are 2 search fields on same page - it works
   intermittently.

Tried to changing form names and script variables.

```
<input id="autocomplete_search"  name="addressA" type="text"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lat"/>
<input type="hidden" name="long"/>


<input id="autocomplete_searchB" name="addressB" type="text"/>
<input type="hidden" name="latB"/>
<input type="hidden" name="longB"/>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    
key=MYKEY&amp;libraries=places"></script>

<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function initialize() {
        var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete_search');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
            $('#lat').val(place.geometry['location'].lat());
            $('#long').val(place.geometry['location'].lng());
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function initialize() {
        var inputB = document.getElementById('autocomplete_searchB');
        var autocompleteB = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputB);
        autocompleteB.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            var placeB = autocomplete.getPlace();

            // place variable will have all the information you are looking for.
            $('#latB').val(placeB.geometry['location'].lat());
            $('#longB').val(placeB.geometry['location'].lng());
        });
    }
</script>
```

Need 2 autocomplete search fields that find street names on same page that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use datalist for autocompletion

```
<input list="autocomplete_search"  name="addressA" type="text"/>
<datalist id="autocomplete_search">
<option value="address1">
<option value="address2">
</datalist>

<input list="autocomplete_searchB"  name="addressA" type="text"/>
<datalist id="autocomplete_searchB">
<option value="address1">
<option value="address2">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Will this not just show address1 and address2 - I need google to show autocomplete street names

Comment: you extract the addresses from google and add it in the datalist like in this. https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/06/14/example-of-a-dynamic-html5-datalist-control